# Java and NodeJs in the same project

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am working on a project to make rest APIs. I am using NodeJS with express. This project also involves complex graph algorithm to run in the background for which I have decided to code in Java and call this Java file from the nodeJS end.

My doubt is that should I stick to code that algorithmic part in nodeJS which I am avoiding due to its asynchronous in nature or coding in JAVA is fine and if coding in JAVA is fine, what is the best way to call this JAVA file. I'll be hosting this in AWS.

Another thing, I can code the above algorithmic part in c++ or python as well, will any of these language give any advantage or JAVA is equally fine.

Thanks a lot in advance and I really need to get this.

Answer (score 0):

The language you use is entirely down to what is the best tool for the job in your particular application, or what your preferred language is, so that's completely up to you.

In terms of calling this code from NodeJS, you are making a REST API, so why not deploy your graph algorithm code as a REST service. That way you can call it from anywhere and the language it's written in really doesn't matter.